# Two nested proxy models and segfault for QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using QTreeView and two QSortFilterProxyModel-based filters.

I need to fetch list of currently displayed items in the QTreeView, so I take selected indices (via ->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes()), pass them into simple recursive function but always get SIGSEGV. On debug I've found where calls stack ends — it's somewhere in QVector::fill.

Maybe I'm doing someting wrong? If I pass indexes through `mapToSource()` I get ALL items, not just displayed ones.

Iterator function is simple:

```
void CollectionTreeWidget::iterator(const QModelIndex & index, QModelIndexList & items)
{
    int count = p->dateFilterProxy->rowCount(index);
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        QModelIndex t = index.child(i, 0);
        iterator(t, items);
    }
}
```

Here `dateFilterProxy` is a model that's used as QTreeView model. Code crashes on `rowCount` call.

Comment: Is there any way `p` or `dateFilterProxy` could have become stale?

Comment: Nope, they are the same on whole application runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found error in the algorithm above, to eliminate segfault we must not count sub-indexes for the index-leaves (i.e. nodes without children).

Comment: So, finally, you shoulb be very accurate when use filter proxies, because if you don't you'll get unexpected segfault.